# How to parse and send whole complicated XML from code in Rails

Tags: ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, soap, savon

So I have this complicated XML and want it to parse it to array and send by Savon to the server. The question is how can I parse parameters?

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <add:MessageID
        xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org">sdhuf78dd67-8932
    </add:MessageID>
    <add:Action
        xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005">http://google/FMP
    </add:Action>
    <add:To
        xmlns:add="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://no1.testbla.com/1HAD9ANA1
    </add:To>
    <link:TransactionFlowLink
        xmlns:link="http://google/2010/06/"/>
        <oas:Security
            xmlns:oas="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <oas:UsernameToken oas1:Id="UsernameToken-1"
                xmlns:oas1="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <oas:Username>AHOJHOLA</oas:Username>
                <oas:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Nonce</oas:Nonce>
                <oas:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">HashedPassword</oas:Password>
                <oas1:Created>CurrentGMTDateAndTime</oas1:Created>
            </oas:UsernameToken>
        </oas:Security>
        <AMA_SecurityHostedUser
            xmlns="http://xml.amfds.com/2010/06">
            <UserID AgentDutyCode="DA" RequestorType="BO" PseudoCityCode="HIATRA67" POS_Type="5"/>
        </AMA_SecurityHostedUser>
</soapenv:Header>
```

I know how to parse for example add:Action without parameter:

```
"add:Action" => "http://google/FMP"
```

And I know that parameter should be written with @ prefix.

But I dont know how to write it together. Is this right?

```
"add:Action" => {
    "@xmlns:add" => "http://www.w3.org/2005",
    "http://google/FMP"
},etc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out this information, you need to go and have a look at the [Gyoku gem](https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku): the gem that Savon uses to translate Ruby hashes into XML.  Specifically, [the documentation on using explicit XML attributes](https://github.com/savonrb/gyoku#explicit-xml-attributes).  Looking at that, we can get the XML you're looking for with the following hash:

```
{
  "add:Action" => {
    "@xmlns:add" => "http://www.w3.org/2005",
    :content! => "http://google/FMP"
  }
}
```

We can test this in IRB directly with Gyoku:

```
irb> require 'gyoku'
# => true
irb> Gyoku.xml({"add:Action" => { "@xmlns:add" => "http://www.w3.org/2005", :content! => "http://google/FMP" } })
# => "<add:Action xmlns:add=\"http://www.w3.org/2005\">http://google/FMP</add:Action>"
```